# Pandas future warning for idxmax() & idxmin() question?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

python 3.9.13, pandas 2.1.3

```
blahblah.py:29: FutureWarning: The behavior of DataFrame.idxmax with all-NA values, or any-NA and skipna=False, is deprecated. In a future version this will raise ValueError   df['max days'] = df[columns].idxmax(axis=1)
```

Same warning with: `skipna=False` or, `skipna=True`

Program works as expected despite warning.

Does anyone know what is going on with this? Google returns nothing useful.

Answer (score 2):

The warning is straightforward, it says it will throw warning in two cases:

1. Your column/row contains all NA values
2. Your column/row contains at least one NA value, and you specify `skipna=False`

The solution is also straightforward:

- For **case 1**: Delete/Fill column/row that contains all NA values
- For **case 2**: Specify `skipna=True`

## `Series.idxmax()` example

I would take `Series.idxmax()` for example first.

Assume I have a following dataframe

```
   col1  col2
0  <NA>  <NA>
1  <NA>     2
```

- `col1` contains all NA values
- `col2` contains one NA value
- `row0` contains all NA values
- `row1` contains one NA value

---

When I use `df['col1'].idxmax()`, it will throw following error:

```
C:\Users\Desktop\1.py:12: FutureWarning: The behavior of Series.idxmax with all-NA values, or any-NA and skipna=False, is deprecated. In a future version this will raise ValueError
  df['idxmax col1'] = df['col1'].idxmax()
```

For `df['col1'].idxmax(skipna=True)`, it is

```
C:\Users\Desktop\1.py:12: FutureWarning: The behavior of Series.idxmax with all-NA values, or any-NA and skipna=False, is deprecated. In a future version this will raise ValueError
  df['idxmax col1'] = df['col1'].idxmax(skipna=True)
```

The problem is that `col1` contains all NA values, so it matches my **case 1** and throws warning no matter you add `skipna`.

---

For `df['col2'].idxmax(skipna=False)` where `col2` contains one NA value, it matches **case 2** and you get the warning

```
C:\Users\Desktop\1.py:11: FutureWarning: The behavior of Series.idxmax with all-NA values, or any-NA and skipna=False, is deprecated. In a future version this will raise ValueError
  df['col2'].idxmax(skipna=False)
```

Reason `df['col2'].idxmax()` doesn't give any warning is that default `skipna` is True for `Series.idxmax()`.

## `DataFrame.idxmax()` example

Back to your `DataFrame.idxmax(axis=1)`, the problem is that one of your row contains all NA values, like `row 0` in my example. Thus, when I use `df.idxmax(axis=1)`, it throws

```
C:\Users\Desktop\1.py:11: FutureWarning: The behavior of DataFrame.idxmax with all-NA values, or any-NA and skipna=False, is deprecated. In a future version this will raise ValueError
  df.idxmax(axis=1)
```

In this situation, you need process the all NA values rows first, like dropping those rows.

```
out = df.dropna(axis=0, how='all')  # Drop rows which contain all NA values.

res = out.idxmax(axis=1)            # skipna for DataFrame.idxmax default is True
```

```
print(out)

   col1 col2
1  <NA>    2

print(res)

1    col2
dtype: object
```

After we drop the rows containing all NA values from `df`, we can safely get the index of first occurrence of maximum over columns with `out.idxmax(axis=1)`.

Note that the row of `out` hits the **case 2**, if we do `out.idxmax(axis=1, skipna=False)`, you will also get warning

```
C:\Users\Desktop\1.py:13: FutureWarning: The behavior of DataFrame.idxmax with all-NA values, or any-NA and skipna=False, is deprecated. In a future version this will raise ValueError
  res = out.idxmax(axis=1, skipna=False)
```

Comment: amazing solution/explanation

Comment: Thanks for the well thought out reply. The problem for me is that I have no NA values in my data frame. I get the same number of rows (6021) before and after out = df.dropna(axis=0, how='all')

Comment: @John If so, you'd better provide a minimal of your data that can reproduce the error for better debugging. You don't need `df.dropna(axis=0, how='all')`, what you need is `df[columns].dropna(axis=0, how='all')`.